# Is it possible to execute a select query and get the same result as at some point in the past for debugging an application?

Tags: sql-server

I sometimes get bug-reports that our application returns wrong values. Wrong values means values which should have had other values at this point of time or contradicting values. As these values change over time and our application consists of multiple systems and users interacting with the same values (we have checks to prevent concurrency issues/race conditions), it is often complex to figure out the value(s) which were returned by the queries at a specific point of time. Currently we use the values at the time we get the bug-report and then use the log-files of our application to revert all changes since the time of the occurence of the "bug" in our head to estimate the values at the reported time. As you can guess this is very complicated/involves much work.

Currently rejected/deferred options:

- get the latest backup before the incident and use db-logfiles for point-in-time recovery -> Because of the size of the database this would take multiple hours
- log every result of select-queries in the application serverside -> This would get additional load to the server because most queries are select statements. Also I would like not to log some data for the same reason you don't log passwords in the log-file.

To give you an example:

1. some values inserted/updated/deleted/queried
2. 10:00 user A uses our application which shows some "wrong" values or does not see them for some reason alltough another user says he inserted the data
3. some values inserted/updated/deleted/queried
4. 11:00 we get bug-report from user A that the query was wrong. Now we want to make the same query to see which result the query initiated by user A at 11:00 should have returned/did return so that we know where to get started looking for the bug or if for example another user changed the value unexpected for user A or didn't have already inserted the data at that time

So is there some way to "look into the past"/see the result of a query in the past?

We use MS-SQL-server with recovery model "Full" and database mirroring.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov  Temporal Tables looks like what I need. I want SQL Server 2016 NOW! ;)

Comment: DW and OLTP are very different creatures so while they seem similar from 100K ft, good luck designing your OLTP app around slowly changing dimensions. Up close, SCD is a very different creature from temporal databases. Temporal databases are intended to solve this class of problems for OLTP apps. DB2, Oracle and now SQL Server have temporal DB features in addition to their existing SCD features. Temporal is what you should explore, not SCD.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 added support for [Temporal Tables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables):

> A system-versioned temporal table is a type of user table designed to keep a full history of data changes, allowing easy point-in-time analysis. This type of temporal table is referred to as a system-versioned temporal table because the period of validity for each row is managed by the system (that is, the database engine).

<sub>(contributed by https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/57105)</sub>